# Spring Application fails to restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-threads

I am adding an endpoint to restart my boot application.

I have followed 2nd opinion (Restart by Creating a New Context) of the following url : https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app

```
@RestController
 public class RestartController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/restart-admin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void restart() {    
            ActivitiAdminCrmMain.restart();
    }

}
public class ActivitiAdminCrmMain {
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    context = SpringApplication.run(ActivitiAdminCrmMain.class, args);
}

public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(ActivitiAdminCrmMain.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```

I am getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/spring.factories]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1325)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:948)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:393)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at storebrand.activiti.admin.ActivitiAdminCrmMain.lambda$0(ActivitiAdminCrmMain.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you try to use `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.getInstance().restart()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

With above devtools dependency, you can try something like below.

```
@RestController
 public class RestartController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/restart-admin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void restart() {    
        org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.getInstance().restart();
    }

}
```